# How to fix END and START values when smoothing a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, plotly

I have a pandas dataframe with some rows and columns. I would like to smooth the values in one of the columns. I am using the following function, which I got from a Lynda tutorial about data processing:

```
def smooth_data(df_block,win=10):
    smoothed = np.correlate(df_block, np.ones(win)/win, 'same')¬
    return smoothed
```

This is the data:

```
(index)          (date)   (close)      (smoothed_close) (val)      
751 2017-03-05 10:00:00  0.000079      0.000039  1.488708e+09
752 2017-03-05 12:00:00  0.000078      0.000059  1.488715e+09
753 2017-03-05 14:00:00  0.000078      0.000078  1.488722e+09
754 2017-03-05 16:00:00  0.000077      0.000078  1.488730e+09
755 2017-03-05 18:00:00  0.000077      0.000077  1.488737e+09
756 2017-03-05 20:00:00  0.000077      0.000077  1.488744e+09
757 2017-03-05 22:00:00  0.000077      0.000077  1.488751e+09
758 2017-03-06 00:00:00  0.000076      0.000077  1.488758e+09
...
```

So when the `close` column is smoothed and stored as `smoothed_close` I am getting deformation at the end and start points once the result is plotted:

[image]

What would be an elegant way to fix the end and start points?

Comment: eliminate the first and last point :D

Comment: Yes :) But maybe there is a more elegant method?